Interpretation of Lévy process with signed Lévy measures
Suppose that I have a non-decreasing, pure jump Lévy process of finite variation $X$ with Lévy measure $\pi$. The Lévy measure is then supported on $(0,+\infty)$. Suppose that the Lévy measure is a signed measure, i.e., the difference of two positive function $f_+$ and $f_-$ such that:
$$
\forall x>0,\quad \pi(\operatorname{d}x) = (f_+(x) - f_-(x))\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)\operatorname{d}x.
$$
If I denote $X_\pm$ the pure-jump processes with Lévy measures $f_\pm$, how can $X$ be intepreted in terms of $X_\pm$ ?
Thank you!

The Lévy measure cannot be a signed measure.

Thanks @IosifPinelis ! do you have any reference of this ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process#L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Khintchine_representation, or any book covering Lévy processes/infinitely divisible distributions.
